# Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned, but can't return null as per other questions, at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using the map function with an if statement that doesn't end in else. I have to be strict that only the defined recourseTypes are shown.

in eslint I get an error on my => as it doesn't end in an else

> Array.prototype.map() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function.

Is there a correct way to write this?

Code:

```
   routes: async () => {
      const apiURL = process.env.BASE_URL
      const response = await axios.get(`${apiURL}/urls`)
      const { data: resources } = response.data
      const urlModule = resources.map((resource) => {
        const { resourceType } = resource

    if (resourceType === 'brand') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.9,
      }
    } else if (resourceType === 'product') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 0.8,
      }
    } else if (resourceType === 'category') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.7,
      }
    } else if (resourceType === 'document') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.6,
      }
    }
  })

  return [
    {
      url: '/',
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: '/account',
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: '/account/order-history',
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
    },
    ...urlModule,
  ]
},
```

Comment: Add an `else` block

Comment: what happens to the default `undefined`? btw, after `return`, you need no `else` statement.

Comment: What _do_ you want to happen if it's not one of those four resource types? Or if they're exhaustive, how is ESLint supposed to know that? Maybe you should ignore the rule? Filter? Add type information (if using TypeScript)? Throw an error in an else case?

Comment: I've updated my full block of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Clarification :*** `resources` array contains all the resourceType that we are comparing using `if/else` clause ? As `Array.map()` will return the same number of elements as input array contains otherwise it will return with undefined.

***Suggestion :*** Instead of multiple `if/else-if` clause, we can use multiple `if` statements for a better performance.

Demo **:**

```js
// Response coming from API.
const resources = [{
  resourceType: 'brand',
  url: 'brandUrl'
}, {
  resourceType: 'product',
  url: 'productUrl'
}, {
  resourceType: 'category',
  url: 'categoryUrl'
}, {
  resourceType: 'document',
  url: 'documentUrl'
}];

// Array of required ResourceTypes. 
const requiredResourceTypes = ['brand', 'product', 'document'];

// Logic to filter and get the URL's object of the required resourceTypes.
const urlModule = resources.filter(({resourceType}) => requiredResourceTypes.includes(resourceType)).map((resource) => {
    const { resourceType } = resource
    if (resourceType === 'brand') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.9,
      }
    }
    if (resourceType === 'product') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 0.8,
      }
    }
    if (resourceType === 'category') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.7,
      }
    }
    if (resourceType === 'document') {
      return {
        url: `/${resource.url}`,
        changefreq: 'weekly',
        priority: 0.6,
      }
    }
  });
  
  console.log(urlModule);
```

Performance test result screenshot **:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but as you can see I am getting the list of URLS from an API and filtering by the defined resourceTypes. There are many others others that I don't want included, how do I define just those?

Comment: @Pianoc in that case, You can first filtered out the required resourceTypes from the api response by using `Array.filter` and then you can use the same logic. Also, Just for the demo i used directly `resources` array. You can replace that with API call. Let me know if you still need any discussion.

Comment: @Pianoc I improved the answer as per your exact requirement. Please have a look. Hope this will work now as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to figure out a default to return in the `else` case. It doesn't technically need to be in an `else` block since you return in the other `if` blocks, it can just be at the end of the function. To ensure that only the allowed `resourceType`s are included, you can return some sort of output that you'll be able to recognize as an "error" if someone isn't using the right `resourceType`. You say you don't want to return `null`, presumably because you don't want that in the final array, so you could just return `null` and then filter with a simple `.filter(item => item)` to make sure everything is truthy, or you could explicitly check for `null`. Either way, you're going to have to return some sort of recognizable "error" default and handle that case.